# SQL Server - how to delete recursive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[image]

I have a `department` table, I want to select and delete all the reference rows of `departmentid` and `departmentidparent` from the table for a department id, let's suppose `departmentid=13`.

That means

```
Departmentid         departmentidparent
13                     13
14                     13
15                     13
16                     14
17                     14
```

In this all the rows should be deleted from the table. I am very confused and don't have any Idea how to solve it.

Comment: So, you want to delete any department that has departmentID = 13 at any level in its ancestry?

Answer (score 7):

With a sample table

```
create table tbl (departmentid int, departmentidparent int)
insert tbl select 13,13
insert tbl select 14,13
insert tbl select 15,13
insert tbl select 16,14
insert tbl select 17,11
insert tbl select 115,17
```

This is the query that will do what you need

```
;with cte as
(
select *
 from tbl
 where departmentid=13
 union all
 select tbl.*
 from tbl
 join cte on tbl.departmentidparent=cte.departmentid
 -- the next line is only required because the sample data has parent=self!
 where tbl.departmentid!=cte.departmentid
)
delete tbl
from cte
where tbl.departmentid = cte.departmentid
```

Comment: No I don't, really. You should give it a try. :)